# Richface Fileupload Button text justification

Tags: jsf, file-upload, richfaces

I have a richface fileupload and the code that I currently have is like so:

```
<rich:fileUpload id="uploadT" addControlLabel="Add" fileUploadListener="#{method.uploadListener}"
    uploadData="#{method.data}" listWidth="100px" listHeight="0px" maxFilesQuantity="1"
    immediateUpload="true" acceptedTypes="xsl" allowFlash="false" status="eventQueueFileUpload">  
    <a4j:support event="onuploadcomplete" reRender="fileUploadPanel" />
</rich:fileUpload>
```

My question is, how can I add text alignment/text justification to the button? Right now, it seems as though the text on the button, which is "Add", aligns to the right and I'd like it to be centered.

Comment: Looks like you're running v. 3.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what seems to work by playing with Firebug on the Richfaces 3.3 demo site:

```
.rich-fileupload-button-content { text-align: center; }
```

That class seems to control the text alignment of the button. Here is the url I was playing with:

http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/fileUpload.jsf